# Birthday torah portion

Tags: torah-study

Is there any significance of correlating the parsha of the week with the week a person is born.

(Putting aside that this will be his "bar mitzvah parsha")

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/926816/jewish/Is-there-any-significance-to-my-Torah-portion.htm

Comment: @Shmuel Thank You, the substance of the article is exactly what i'm looking for, but with more rabbinic sources.